# Regular expressions in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to retrieve a string from a text file which appears between two values. For example, I need to retrieve the string between `< postcode >W12 FGS < /postcode >`  and then place a space in that string, so it looks like `< postcode >W12 FGS < /postcode >`. This file can contain over 100 postcode's. How can I do it?

Comment: Yup, for an accurate answer, you need accurate information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very precise when dealing with regex, anyway, based on your request I'd go with:

```
$pattern = [regex]::escape('< postcode >W12FGS < /postcode >')
$replaceWith = '< postcode >W12 FGS < /postcode >'

(Get-Content .\postcode.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $pattern,$replaceWith } |
Set-Content .\postcode.txt
```

Updated based on comments, changing postcode for multiple xml's in of folder.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\postcodes -Filter *.xml | Foreach-Object{
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $xml.SelectNodes('//c_postcode') | Foreach-Object{ $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Insert(3,' ') }
    $xml.Save($_.FullName) 
}
```

Comment: If the data is an XML, then a regex is probably not the best answer. Of course we have no way of knowing for sure if it is XML or not.

Comment: It will work as long as the content is made of text, but if it is an XML then there are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it won't work, just that it probably isn't best.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html  :)

Comment: The files come in as XML format, however I need to process this into a AS400 system which means I have to convert to text (rename to text file), once I have renamed to text file I combine all the text files into 1 big file and then import into AS400. Is there a way I can amend the postcode in the multiple XML that I receive?

Comment: Yes, sharing the structure of the file could help a lot.

Comment: The merged xml's(text file) will look like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><application><stage0><c_terms_agree>Yes</c_terms_agree><c_postcode>123456</c_postcode></stage5></application>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><application><stage0><c_terms_agree>Yes</c_terms_agree><c_postcode>456789</c_postcode></stage5></application> - Thanks Sayful

Comment: Once the xml files come in i need to place a space in the post code i.e <c_postcode>123456</c_postcode> should look like ><c_postcode>123 456</c_postcode>. The xml files are not all the same character length so the postcode on line one can start at the 10th character on one line and 25th character on the second line (i hope that makes sense) - Thanks Sayful

Comment: Try this: [xml]$xml = c:\postcode.xml; $xml.SelectNodes('//c_postcode') | Foreach-Object{ $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Insert(3,' ') }; $xml.Save('c:\postcode.xml')

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect, however how do I do this if I have a multiple xml's in of folder that needs the postcode changing.